# How can I use a network-connected HP All-in-One to scan on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, scanning, hp-laserjet, all-in-one

I have an HP LaserJet All-in-One connected to my home network router.
When I had Windows 7 I was able to scan documents to my computer using the default scanning software that came with Windows.

I have upgraded to Windows 8, and now I can't seem to use the scanning functionality of my All-in-One. The only scanning software that seems to be included with Windows is "Windows Fax and Scan", but when I try to use it to scan I get an error message: "No scanners were detected".

I was then amazed to [discover](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03501661) that on Windows 8, the HP All-in-Ones support scanning only via a direct USB connection, and not via a network connection.

I am quite mad that I have lost this functionality which I paid for when I (quite recently) bought the HP All-in-One, and I wonder if there is any workaround that will nevertheless allow me to scan via a network connection.

Comment: you might post the full product number of your HP AIO

Answer (score 2):

Not much you can do if [HP does not support scanning](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03501661#A1) from the network in Windows 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue trying to scan on my windows 10 from my network attached HP Officejet 6500A Plus. Finally found the solution. I downloaded the [HP All-in-One Printer Remote app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.printercontrol). Once it was installed, and I opened it, I clicked on Select Device, under Settings. The app detected my network printer; I selected it; and the rest is history. Super simple and intuitive app! Yay!